# ViewDidLoad success block called after cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios

I have an api call to store some data to a array property on a table view.

I make the call in the `viewDidLoad` and it all goes well except it runs the api call up to the line before success.

Then it jumps to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to where I set the data I get from the call to a `NSDictionary` then after that line it doesn't complete the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. It jumps back up and runs the success code of the api call before resuming back to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

***The line that it gets to in viewDidLoad is the one directly before the success block:***

`[manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)`

***It then jumps to this line in cellForRowAtIndexPath:***

`NSDictionary *user = self.user[0];`

*Here is my full code:*

**viewDidLoad Method:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    GFCredentialStore *credentialStore = [[GFCredentialStore alloc] init];

    NSString *authToken = [credentialStore authToken];
    NSLog(@"%@", authToken);

    __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

    NSString *userID = self.userID;

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%s%@%@", kBaseURL, kUserURL, userID, @".json"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [GFUserResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"auth_token"];
    NSLog(@"%@", manager.requestSerializer.HTTPRequestHeaders);
    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        __strong typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.user = (NSArray *)responseObject;
        [strongSelf.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath Method:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(indexPath.section == 0){

        GFProfileCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"profileCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSDictionary *user = self.user[0];

        cell.usernameLabel.text = user[@"username"];

        cell.bioLabel.text = user[@"description"];

        NSString * avatarURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%s%@%s%@%s", kBaseURL, "system/users/avatars/", user[@"id"], "/original/", user[@"username"], ".png"];

        NSString * newAvatarURL = [avatarURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];

        [cell.avatarImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newAvatarURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Zoo.png"]];

        cell.avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = 40;
        cell.avatarImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        [cell.followingCountBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(followingBtnClick:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [cell.followerCountBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(followerBtnClick:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];

        // edit profile becomes follow
        cell.editProfileButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
        cell.editProfileButton.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x1FAA4E).CGColor;
        cell.editProfileButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        cell.editProfileButton.titleLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x1FAA4E);

        return cell;

    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1){

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;

    }
    else {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"postsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your problem? Is it crashing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API you are using (`AFNetworking`) is asynchronous, so the success-block will naturally only get executed after the data has been received from the network.

In the meantime, the tableview will already have begun loading your data.

During this period, you could show a progress-indicator (or loading animation), or you could load the data beforehand, if possible (it seems you are loading the data for the logged-in user, so it might be a good idea to load this when your app starts anyway).

Comment: +1. And just to clarify, this isn't an AFNetworking-only issue - this is a pattern you'll need to learn because data may show up quickly, or it may show up slowly, or it may not show up at all.  (Your view controller or table delegate methods should be able to tell which state the data is in, and display appropriately to the user.  Right now you're assuming the data is already there.)

Comment: Very true. While there are synchronous networking APIs out there (such as `NSURLConnection`s `sendSynchronousRequest:...` method), it  is generally a bad idea to use synchronous network calls while working on the main thread.

Comment: generally = always :)

Comment: @AaronBrager & David ok thanks for your responses and help. How exactly do I delay the table view cellForRowAtIndexPath until the data is fully loaded. The data API call needs to be made on this view as it shows a user profile and the user could be any user.

Comment: A simple way would be to do what Aaron suggested and keep track of your the state of the data within the view controller. For example, you could simply set a flag `dataAvailable` to `NO` before making the API call and return 0 in `numberSectionsInTableView` while this flag evaluates to false. (Of course, don't forget to set the flag to `YES` and call `[self.tableView reloadData]` when the API call completes.)